# jquery mouseover div affects another div

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have

**HTML:**

```
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="sdf">sdf</div>
<div class="lol">lol</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").on({
        mouseover: function(){
            $(this).next('.lol').addClass('hide');
        },
        mouseout: function(){
            $(this).next('.lol').removeClass('hide');    
        }
    });
});
```

If I takeout the `<div class="sdf">sdf</div>` in my html the hover works, but is there a way to make this hover work when there is another div in between test and lol on my html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `.lol` is not the next sibling of `.test` it is the next sibling of next element.

You can use .siblings() if there is no other `lol` element within the same parent

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").on({
        mouseover: function(){
            $(this).siblings('.lol').addClass('hide');
        },
        mouseout: function(){
            $(this).siblings('.lol').removeClass('hide');    
        }
    });
});
```

else use

```
$(this).next().next('.lol')....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this, see how it works http://jsfiddle.net/nLybj/4/:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").hover(function () {
        $(this).nextAll('.lol').toggleClass("hide");
    });
});
```